# SQL SERVER 2008 ERROR IN INNER JOIN STATEMENT

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a hard time figuring out what the error is. This query gives me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'." Any help will do. Thank you.

```
select s.id, s.lastname, s.firstname, s.course, c.id, 
       dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) as deptName 
from student s 
inner join course c on s.course = c.id 
where dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) = 'SCHOOL OF ENGINEERING'
      AND s.id in select studno from student_load where right(offer_id,3) = '112'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parantheses. Change your query like so.

```
select s.id, s.lastname, s.firstname, s.course, c.id, 
    dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) as deptName from student s inner join 
   course c on s.course = c.id 
    where dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) = 'SCHOOL OF ENGINEERING'
    AND s.id in (select studno from student_load where right(offer_id,3) = '112')
```

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it if you find the answer helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a newbie here in stackoverflow. What should I mark? The check button?

Comment: Just click the Up arrow before my answer (on its left side).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, missing parantheses in sub-query

```
 select s.id, s.lastname, s.firstname, s.course, c.id, 
        dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) as deptName from student s inner join 
       course c on s.course = c.id 
        where dbo.FUNC_GETDEPARTMENTNAME(c.dept_id) = 'SCHOOL OF ENGINEERING'
        AND s.id in (select studno from student_load where right(offer_id,3) = '112')
```